# Jenkins ssl issue

Tags: ssl, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Lately One of our  jenkins instance failed to start, We are Using jenkins 2.190.3, I see a bunch of ssl errors when its trying to download the plugins.

Unfortunately we login using saml and i'm unable to login until the plugin is installed.(Jenkins is installed and runs on eks), I tried to update to http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json but looks like it still uses the default, (https://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json)

I think the issue is related to this: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/360050702551-Jenkins-Update-Center-root-CA-certificate-expiration-October-2021?page=13

docker-image we are using: https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags?page=1&name=2.190.3

Can someone pls let me know if it was solved on later version of 2.235.1.2. I did try to use 2.235.4 but got the same error.

Any other solution that would solve this error would also be helpful.

Updated:

> ```
>    hudson.model.UpdateCenter.xml: |-
>      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>      <sites>
>         <site>
>            <id>default</id>
>            <url>http://updates.jenkins.io/update-center.json</url>
>         </site>
>      </sites>
> ```

Error:

```
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
20:48:06 Failure (60) Retrying in 1 seconds...
20:48:06 Failure (60) Retrying in 1 seconds...
20:48:06 Failure (60) Retrying in 1 seconds...
20:48:06 Failure (60) Retrying in 1 seconds...
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
```

Comment: If by "lately", you might mean "after Spet 30", then mayve it's a [Let's Encrypt DST Root CA X3 Expiration ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/dst-root-ca-x3-expiration-september-2021/) issue. Heard it had widespread effects.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this..
updated ssl certificates in my docker image

```
   apt-get update && apt-get install openssl ca-certificates \
     && rm /usr/share/ca-certificates/mozilla/DST_Root_CA_X3.crt \
     && update-ca-certificates
```